# MARIE assembler - how to multiply

Tags: c++, assembly, marie

I want to write a simple M.A.R.I.E. program to evaluate the expression `A x B + C x D`.

Now, there's not alot of info on Marie assembly language.
I am not sure if there is a multiply? If not, would I have to loop or something to get it to multiply?
I know for certain operators like `<`, `>` you would subtract.

This is what I have so far:

```
100     load    A
101     load    B
102     add     C   // add to B? b+c?
103     mult    A
```

I'm just stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do I suppose you refer to this?

http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~jeff/notes/compiler/Marie/

You can access to a list of opcodes in the editor (File>>Edit), Help>>Help.
There is no **mult** opcode, so you'll have to create a loop and use **skipcond** in order to test the condition.